# Datatable jquery solo ordena dia/mes y no la fecha completa

Tags: html, jquery, datatables

Resulta que tengo una tabla con las siguientes columnas (no esta todo la tabla si no las columnas, para poner el ejemplo):

```
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th style="display:none;">ID</th>
                        <th>Nombre Material</th>
                        <th style="width:30%">Nº Parte</th>
                        <th>Aprobado</th>
                        <th>REV</th>
                        <th>Diámetro</th>
                        <th>Largo</th>
                        <th>Top</th>
                        <th>Bottom</th>
                        <th>Otros</th>
                        <th>Dado/Dia</th>
                        <th>Uni/Cajas</th>
                        <th class="rotate"><div><span>Orden Interna</span></div></th>
                        <th class="rotate"><div><span>Plano de Corte</span></div></th>
                        <th class="rotate"><div><span>Plano Marcación</span></div></th>
                        <th class="rotate"><div><span>Instruc. de Trabajo</span></div></th>
                        <th class="rotate"><div><span>Plano Especifica</span></div></th>
                        <th class="rotate"><div><span>Instruc.Sheet Cliente</span></div></th>
                        <th class="rotate"><div><span>Drawing Cliente</span></div></th>
                        <th>Última orden emitida</th>
                        <th>Cliente Final</th>
                        <th>Editar Datos</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
```

Estoy organizando la tabla utilizando `rowGroup` para poner todas filas en un conjunto similar (cada una con su familia), el codigo que uso para eso es este:

```
//SE INICIALIZA LA TABLA
    $('.tablaPulse').DataTable({
        "aoColumns": [
            null,
            null,
            null,
            { "sType": "date" },
            null,
            null,
            null,
            null,
            null,
            null,
            null,
            null,
            null,
            null,
            null,
            null,
            null,
            null,
            null,
            { "sType": "date" },
            null,
            null
        ],
        "columnDefs": [
            { "visible": false, "targets": 1 },
            {
                "targets": 3,
                //type: 'datetime-moment'
                "render": $.fn.dataTable.moment('YYYY/MM/DD', 'DD/MM/YYYY')
            }
        ],
        //order: [[1, 'asc']],
        rowGroup: {
            startRender: function (rows, group) {
                return $('<tr/>')
                    .append('<td  class="numPul" bgcolor="#78923B">' + group + '</td>')
                    .append('<td  class="numPul" bgcolor="#78923B"></td>')
                    .append('<td  bgcolor="#78923B"></td>')
                    .append('<td  bgcolor="#78923B"></td>')
                    .append('<td  bgcolor="#78923B"></td>')
                    .append('<td  bgcolor="#78923B"></td>')
                    .append('<td  bgcolor="#78923B"></td>')
                    .append('<td  bgcolor="#78923B"></td>')
                    .append('<td  bgcolor="#78923B"></td>')
                    .append('<td  bgcolor="#78923B"></td>')
                    .append('<td  bgcolor="#78923B"></td>')
                    .append('<td  bgcolor="#78923B"></td>')
                    .append('<td  bgcolor="#78923B"></td>')
                    .append('<td  bgcolor="#78923B"></td>')
                    .append('<td  bgcolor="#78923B"></td>')
                    .append('<td  bgcolor="#78923B"></td>')
                    .append('<td  bgcolor="#78923B"></td>')
                    .append('<td  bgcolor="#78923B"></td>')
                    .append('<td  bgcolor="#78923B"></td>')
                    .append('<td  bgcolor="#78923B"></td>');
            },
            endRender: null,
            dataSrc: 1
        }
    });
```

La tabla se ve de la siguiente manera:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cuando trato de ordenar todo por fecha, el me ordena todo por `dia/mes` y no en su fecha, por ejemplo, en este caso me ordena las fechas del 31 para abajo y omite los años

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El codigo donde inicializo la tabla era mas pequeño, fui agregando diversas ejemplos de codigo que vi en internet y no me funcionan, las partes de codigo que agregue fue:

```
 "aoColumns": [
        null,
        null,
        null,
        { "sType": "date" },
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        { "sType": "date" },
        null,
        null
    ],
```

y

```
{      "targets": 3,
        //type: 'datetime-moment'
        "render": $.fn.dataTable.moment('YYYY/MM/DD', 'DD/MM/YYYY')
}
```

y aun asi nada funciona, que puedo modificar o agregar para que pueda ordernar las fechas como debe?

PD: ya agregue `moment.js` por aquello

Answer (score 0):

Creo que el problema es que te falta un '.render' en el código con el que capturas la fecha. Prueba con algo así:

```js
"columnDefs": [
            { "visible": false, "targets": 1 },
            {
                "targets": 3,
                //type: 'datetime-moment'
                "render": $.fn.dataTable.render.moment('YYYY/MM/DD', 'DD/MM/YYYY')
            }
        ],
```

Comparto aquí un enlace sobre como implemente 'dataTables' que creo que te puede resultar de ayuda: [DataTables-DateTime](https://datatables.net/plug-ins/dataRender/datetime)